# decompress (unzip) file in java that have been compressed by .net system.io.compression.gzipstream

Tags: java, .net, gzip

I have a file that has been compressed (zip) by a .net application using `system.io.compression.gzipstream` library.
I tried to decompress (unzip) it using `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` in java. 
it threw:

> java.io.EOFException
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:246)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:237)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUInt(GZIPInputStream.java:229)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readTrailer(GZIPInputStream.java:197)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:92)
>       at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
>       at juwdemoproj.FileWriterTest.gunzipIt(FileWriterTest.java:353)
>       at juwdemoproj.FileWriterTest.main(FileWriterTest.java:51)

My sample code:

```
    public static void gunzipIt() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    String zipFilePath = "C:\\Juw\\JR\\file\\output\\020030214112016.zip";
    String destDirectory = "C:\\Juw\\JR\\file\\output\\targetUnzip";

    try {
        GZIPInputStream gzis =
            new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destDirectory);

        int len;
        while ((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        gzis.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Question:
- Is it possible to unzip the file in java, when the file was compressed by a .net application?
- Any zip library that can achieve the above requirement?

Thanks

Comment: ZIP and GZip are two different and incompatible formats. I suggest you open the .zip as a ZIP not as a .gz file.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, OP did say it was compressed using .NET's `gzipstream`, so it may just be that the file extension is wrong. Either way, OP does seem to confuse Zip vs GZip, since a zipped file should have a `.zip` file extension, and a gzipped file should have a `.gz` file extension.

Comment: hi @PeterLawrey, yes my client save it as a .zip file extension, but they using the gzipstream library. i can see it in their code.

Comment: @Andreas, is the extension naming have any effect when i tried to decompress it in java ?

Comment: @cumibulat File extension has no meaning for your code, but it confuses the issue when a file has the wrong extension, since zip and gzip are two entirely different incompatible file formats. --- Anyway, to test file integrity, try decompressing the file using the `gunzip` command. Doesn't come with Windows, so you'll need to download one from the web.

Comment: This error suggests the file was truncated. Did they close the stream correctly. Can it be read by other tools?

Comment: Good unit test would be to check if they can read it themselves using .NET. If *they* can't read it, you *know* the file is bad. The fact that they created a gzipped file with a .zip extension do indicate that they may not know what they are doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey when i decompress it using 7zip it throwing some error, but i can still use the output file.

Comment: @PeterLawrey if i open it directly using the windows explorer, it saying file is invalid. when i decompress it using winrar, no error and the file decompressed successfully.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your input, will try the gunzip. and re-check with the client's .net code.

Comment: @cumibulat if the tailer is corrupt or missing, it might be possible to read the file which is before it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it solve my issue.

```
public void gunzipIt(){

 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 boolean isValid = true;

 try{

     GZIPInputStream gzis =
        new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(INPUT_GZIP_FILE));

     FileOutputStream out =
        new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE);

    while (isValid) {

        int len;

        try{
            len = gzis.read(buffer);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            len = 0;
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (len > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }else{

            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    gzis.close();
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

at the end of the file there is a empty string, so it throwing error. i get this code from my colleague and it works.